# How to select bluetooth protocol a react native library?

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rfcomm

I have a bluetooth le server running on an embedded linux system listening on RFCOMM port and I can connect to it using apps from playstore that emulate serial terminal. I want to write an app in react native that can connect to it.

I have found these two following libraries [react native ble manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager), [react native ble plx](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx), but can not find any reference to RFCOMM. Searching through the repos I can't find any reference to any protocol to be honest, whether that is RFCOMM L2CAP or OBEX.

Examples only show how write/read happens, but as opposed to other lower level libraries such as bluez there is no mention of protocol used. Are those libraries restricted to only one way of communicating and as such it is redundant to state what underlying protocol is being utilised?

Comment: RFCOMM is Bluetooth Classic. Do you want to use Bluetooth Classic or Bluetooth Low Energy?

Comment: wow, I didn't know that. need to do more reading I guess. Thanks